# validateDOMNesting(...): <h4> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>

Tags: reactjs

how to solve this issue validateDOMNesting(...):  cannot appear as a descendant of

?

```
    <Row>
      <Col xs="12" md="12" lg="12" >
        <Card >
          <CardHeader>
            <h4>Sample Information</h4>
          </CardHeader>
          <CardBody>
            <Form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}> 
              ....
            </Form>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </Col>
    </Row>
```

Comment: Hello, can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example, one that includes any JSX using a `<p />` that is possibly enclosing more components?

Comment: Normally CardHeader has a text prop that you can use. Why don't you try that instead of trying to put a h4 inside p which violates the basic rules of HTML